# Why didn't the Cousins attack Hank at the same time?

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad

In Breaking Bad, cousins were experienced hitmen and had been planning this attack for some time. It seems extremely sloppy that they didn't coordinate before the attack. I know it had to happen this way for the story, but it still bothers me why they didn't attack Hank at the same time?

Comment: Honestly, as far as 'plot holes' go - the idea that someone might be a little overconfident surprising a middle aged DEA agent in a car park - doesn't seem that bad.

Comment: Agreed, but you figure that the twins both would have wanted a hand in killing him.

Comment: Henchmen **always** attack one at a time. It's an unwritten law, narrative imperative… or a written [*trope*](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MookChivalry)

Comment: "It seems extremely sloppy" — based on your extensive experience as a cartel hit man? Cool.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing perhaps the most fundamental thing that occurred in that scene.

**Hank was warned.**

Who's to say that without their target being alerted to the impending attack, Marco would have had a chance to get into position to open fire at the same moment as Leonel, catching Hank in a fatal crossfire?